# mysql error 1064: after update to mysql 5.6.31 from mysql 5.5.50-cll

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

I am moving my website to new host, and I have this error:

Notice: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
   use near `oc_first_page_content` at line 1

```
Error No: 1064  
SELECT content, link, background FROM `oc_first_page_content`
    in /home/tiffanyd/public_html/system/library/db/mysqli.php on line 41
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/tiffanyd/public_html/catalog/controller/module/html.php on line 14
```

and here is the mysql code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oc_first_page_content` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `content_en` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(240) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `background` varchar(240) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;
```

how can fix that? :(

Comment: I can not see any error if i try it in sqlfiddle

Comment: works fine on 5.6.31 , works fine on 5.7.13

Comment: Your error shows a SELECT, where is the code with your SELECT query.

Comment: your error has absolutely nothing to do with this bit of SQL

Comment: I checked. Its okay.

Comment: @Jens this is my website address: www.tiffanydaily,ir and you can see the error there

Comment: @Drew but my website has error :( check my website tiffanydaily.ir

Comment: @Devon I can send to you my database, if you send me your email

Comment: @e4c5 yeah, but I dont know exactly where is the problem

Comment: @AmranurRahman Thank you, but it's not working and I dont know why

Comment: This is not the create statement where the error comes from it is a select statment: `SELECT content,link,background FROM ```oc_first_page_content` as i can see

Comment: Can you show this part of your code?

Comment: i find that, error was in query code and i fixed that, Thank you all